# Python code running slow

Tags: python

Python code running extremely slow.  Starts fast, then turns into a crawl.  ANything I can do to speed things up?  I'm pulling up a text file, reading the contents of the file, filtering the contents of the text file, and writing that to a csv for later use by someone else for json.

I just started doing this, as I am sure you can tell. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
import glob
from pathlib import Path
import datetime
import re
import csv


get_this = []
thislist = []

def timeteller():
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    month = str('{:02d}'.format(now.month))
    day1 = now.day -1
    day =  str('{:02d}'.format(day1))
    year =str(now.year)
    time =year+month+day
    return time

def these_files(x, y):

    configfiles = Path('O:/Unit Management/Reports/G4S/').glob('{}*/{}*Transaction.txt'.format(x, y))

    for files in configfiles:
        thislist.append(files)

    return thislist

def hasNumbers(inputString):
    numberfinal = []
    numberfinal = re.findall("\d+", inputString)
    if numberfinal == []:
        numberfinal = '1'
    return numberfinal

def get_odometers(thesepath):

    for thispath in thesepath:

        with open(thispath,"r") as f:
            searchlines = f.readlines()
        for i, line in enumerate(searchlines):
            if "Odometers" in line:
                get_this.append(line)
            elif "Lifetime" in line:
                get_this.append(line)


    return get_this

def make_pretty(checkthis):
    the_numbers = {}
    the_numbers['Serial'] = banumber
    for i, line in enumerate(checkthis):
        the_numbers['Serial'] = banumber
        if '(BNR) Odometers  Accept' in line:
            for l in checkthis[i:i+2]: 
                numbers = l[0:20]
                numberschecked = hasNumbers(numbers)
                the_numbers['BNR'] = numberschecked[0]
        elif '(BNR 2) Odometers  Accept' in line:
            for l in checkthis[i:i+2]: 
                numbers = l[0:20]
                numberschecked = hasNumbers(numbers)
                the_numbers['BNR 2'] = numberschecked[0]
        elif '(BCR) Odometers  Accept' in line:
            for l in checkthis[i:i+2]: 
                numbers = l[0:20]
                numberschecked = hasNumbers(numbers)
                the_numbers['BCR'] = numberschecked[0]
        elif '(BCR) Odometers  Hopper1' in line:
            for l in checkthis[i:i+2]:
                numbers = l[0:20]
                numberschecked = hasNumbers(numbers)
                the_numbers['Hopper1'] = numberschecked[0]
        elif '(BCR) Odometers  Hopper2' in line:
            for l in checkthis[i:i+2]: 
                numbers = l[0:20]
                numberschecked = hasNumbers(numbers)
                the_numbers['Hopper2'] = numberschecked[0]
        elif '(BCR) Odometers  Hopper3' in line:
            for l in checkthis[i:i+2]: 
                numbers = l[0:20]
                numberschecked = hasNumbers(numbers)
                the_numbers['Hopper3'] = numberschecked[0]
        elif '(BCR) Odometers  Hopper4' in line:
            for l in checkthis[i:i+2]: 
                numbers = l[0:20]
                numberschecked = hasNumbers(numbers)
                the_numbers['Hopper4'] = numberschecked[0]
        elif '(BCR) Odometers  Hopper5' in line:
            for l in checkthis[i:i+2]: 
                numbers = l[0:20]
                numberschecked = hasNumbers(numbers)
                the_numbers['Hopper5'] = numberschecked[0]
        elif '(BCR) Odometers  Hopper6' in line:
            for l in checkthis[i:i+2]: 
                numbers = l[0:20]
                numberschecked = hasNumbers(numbers)
                the_numbers['Hopper6'] = numberschecked[0]
        elif '(BCR) Odometers  Hopper7' in line:
            for l in checkthis[i:i+2]: 
                numbers = l[0:20]
                numberschecked = hasNumbers(numbers)
                the_numbers['Hopper7'] = numberschecked[0]
        elif '(BCR) Odometers  Hopper8' in line:
            for l in checkthis[i:i+2]: 
                numbers = l[0:20]
                numberschecked = hasNumbers(numbers)
                the_numbers['Hopper8'] = numberschecked[0]


    return the_numbers

intnow = int(timeteller())
intnow -= 1
now = str(intnow)
thelist = []
thispath = open('banumberlist1.txt')
finallist = []
for files in thispath:
    getem = files
    banumber = getem[0:8]
    print(banumber)
    combined = '{}_{}'.format(banumber,now)
    thepaths = these_files(banumber, combined)
    needtomakepretty = get_odometers(thepaths)
    goeslast = make_pretty(needtomakepretty)
    finallist.append(goeslast)


f = open ('odom01.txt', 'w')
for ba in finallist:
    sba = str(ba)
    f.write(sba)
```

Comment: Have you checked memory usage? Or profiled it?

Comment: On my computer it's running about 40 %

Comment: how many files ? how do you know it is first fast then getting slow ? please provide input and expected output so we can reproduce.

Comment: roughly 5000  the input are

Comment: BA-03556
BA-02743
BA-02567
BA-02480

Comment: output {'Serial': 'BA-02926', 'BNR': '5262391', 'BNR 2': '4547649', 'BCR': '15421640', 'Hopper1': '42183', 'Hopper2': '476048', 'Hopper3': '40220', 'Hopper4': '13093', 'Hopper5': '45136', 'Hopper6': '11022', 'Hopper7': '21542', 'Hopper8': '57342'}

Comment: I know it gets slower because of the print(banumber) statement

Comment: Running the same code on about 100 files takes seconds.

Comment: i think you have a problem with `get_this` and `thislist`. those are never reset

Comment: BOBROBBADASSBOBROB!  You resolved it!  One hell of an eye my brother!  THank you so much!!!!!!  My script is humming like a ferrari

Comment: How do I solve your answer as the answer?

Answer (score 5):

If you want to know which part of your code is slow, you will need to use a profiler.

You could use `cProfile` which is part of the standard library:

```
python -m cProfile -o profile.txt -s cumtime myscript.py
```

This will write the profiling results to `profile.txt`, sorting the profile by cumulative time.
This will give you an overview of where your program is spending its time.

---

For a more detailed view, you could use the [line_profiler](https://github.com/rkern/line_profiler) module. This can even show you how much time every line of code uses.

After installing `line_profiler`, add the following to the beginning of your script:

```
import line_profiler
import atexit
profile = line_profiler.LineProfiler()
atexit.register(profile.print_stats)
```

Now add the `@profile` decorators to all your functions, like so:

```
@profile
def timeteller():
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    month = str('{:02d}'.format(now.month))
    day1 = now.day -1
    day =  str('{:02d}'.format(day1))
    year =str(now.year)
    time =year+month+day
    return time
```

You should put the stuff at the end of your script into a function (e.g. `main`) and add `@profile` to that as well.

Now run your script, and you will see a profile.

Comment: @MelvinAbraham When using `cProfile` you will see a lot of stuff about the internals of Python. Using `line_profiler` you have more control over what is profiled.